# How to use thirdparty library in my app?

Tags: android, apache

I  have come across MiT,apache licences in libraries.so if I use the libraries and make some apps,can i put ads in my apps?where to include licence in my app/project?

Comment: just add licence directly to your app (As a list of libraries with there licence)

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/RobertFischer/Gradle-License-Report.

Comment: bro where to add please elaborate.

Comment: You can use the ad, while some libraries such as last.fm would demand profit shares. Read condition before using libraries. You can add libraries in Gradle and their respective licences in about your app (Licences Activity)